# "Add" button while Editing , actionClicked sender

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a TableView Controller called Ingr. In it there's a list of items. I set the Edit button plus the Delete function. Now , i am trying to set the add function because those items must be added by users. My problem is that the Add button is hidden untill you click the edit button. Thus, i cannot make a segue from storyboard because i don't see the button.I need to switch to another controller when Add is clicked. I tried to solve it in this way :

ViewControllerIngr.h

```
@interface ViewControllerIngr : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate>

-(IBAction) editButtonClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) addAction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) doneAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewControllerIngr.m

```
-(IBAction)editButtonClicked:(id)sender

{

[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];


UIBarButtonItem *addBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addBtn;

    UIBarButtonItem *fattoBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = fattoBtn;

}

-(void)doneAction:(id)sender{
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editButtonClicked:)];



}


-(IBAction)addAction:(id)sender{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerInfo *info = (ViewControllerInfo*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];

[self presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I just wanted to copy here all the 3 button sender to be more clear. However the only one that i have written and i don't know if is wrong or right is the addAction , considering that when it switched i can't see what i designed inside the ViewControllerInfo.

I didn't edit in any way the ViewControllerInfo.h and ViewControllerInfo.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a segue in your storyboard without linking it to a specific button.

You need to create a segue from one ViewController to the other - you do this by control-clicking from the ViewController (it's probably easiest to drag from the very top, where the status bar would be) and dragging to the other. Then, select the segue, and in the inspector on the right hand side, give it an identifier.

Then, in code, you can perform this segue, using its identifier, like so:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: Fantastic! Best Option :)

Answer (score 0):

First, in the attribute inspector of your .xib file, make a identifier for that view or nib file; suppose it is *info*

If you are using `NavigationController`

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerInfo *info = (ViewControllerInfo*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];
```